# Show that $(1 – \cos θ – \sin θ )^2 – 2(1 – \sin θ )(1 – \cos θ ) = 0$.

Tags: trigonometry

Show that $(1 – \cos θ – \sin θ )^2 – 2(1 – \sin θ )(1 – \cos θ ) = 0$.

What kind of formulas should I use?

Comment: This problem seems to be very easy. Did you attempt it?

Comment: Expand. The only formula you will need is the familiar $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe 
\begin{align}
(1-\cos\theta-\sin\theta)^2 & =(1-\cos\theta)^2-2(1-\cos\theta)\sin\theta+\sin^2\theta \\
& = 1 - 2\cos\theta+\color{red}{\cos^2\theta}-2(1-\cos\theta)\sin\theta+\color{red}{\sin^2\theta} \\
& = 1+\color{red}{1}-2\cos\theta -2(1-\cos\theta)\sin\theta\\
& =2(1-\cos\theta)-2(1-\cos\theta)\sin\theta\\
& =2(1-\cos\theta)(1-\sin\theta)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

LHS = $1 - 2\cos\theta - 2\sin\theta + 2\cos(\theta)\sin\theta + \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta -2 + 2\cos\theta + 2\sin\theta -2\cos(\theta)\sin\theta = 0$ = RHS

Comment: Glad to see you formatting your answers! Tip: Instead of `$cos\theta$` = $cos\theta$, try `$\cos\theta$` = $\cos\theta$. Ditto for the $\sin$ function.

Comment: @amWhy: cheers.